# XCode 7.3 bug with code marking (in Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7.3

In XCode 7.3, document items (toggled with ctrl-6) is not displaying properly beyond a certain point. (There is nothing wrong above the screen shot)

[image: //MARK: - Not showing properly]

Answer (score 0):

Not many people will experience this since it happens (as far as I've found out) in specific situations.

```
let i = 0
switch i {
default: "\(i) ©"
}
```

Copy and pasting the above code will make the same thing happen in any file with `// MARK:` `// FIXME:` `// TODO:` code markings.

The condition for this to happen is the combination of the three:

1. Using `switch`: `if {}` won't cause the same problem.
2. Using string interpolation: `String(format: "%d ©", i)` or `"stringText ©"` won't cause the same problem.
3. Using Emoji & Symbols with a space in front: `"\(i)©"` won't cause the same problem.

Any one of the three conditions are not met, the bug won't happen. So in case you look at document items a lot and don't want to see the mangled dropdown list, try changing any one of three conditions.